# When retrieving a specific value from an object, the entire object is returned instead of just the value needed

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, object

I'm trying to retrieve a value (let poster : String?):

```
public struct GenrePosters: Decodable {

  public let poster : String? //This string is what I'm trying to get

  public init? (json: JSON) {

  self.poster = "poster_path" <~~ json
  }
```

This function is used to update the data:

```
 static func updateGenrePoster(genreID: NSNumber, urlExtension: String, completionHandler:@escaping (_ details: [GenrePosters]?) -> Void){

let nm = NetworkManager.sharedManager

nm.getJSONData(type:"genre/\(genreID)", urlExtension: urlExtension, completion: {
  data in

  if let jsonDictionary = nm.parseJSONData(data)
  {
    guard let genrePoster = ResultsGenrePosters(json: jsonDictionary)

      else {
        print("Error initializing object")
        return
    }
    guard let posterString = genrePoster.results
      else {
        print("No such item")
        return
    }

    completionHandler(posterString)//Returns an array
  }
})
```

}
}

It appears that the above function is properly returning an array, but they are in the format:

> GenrePosters(poster: Optional("/e1mjopzAS2KNsvpbpahQ1a6SkSn.jpg"))

When I try and use the poster string to plug into an URL it plugs the entire above value instead of just the ".jpg"

```
  func updateUI()// updates Tableview IBOutlets
  {
    genreCatagoryLabel.text = genreData.name

    if let genreID = genreData.id {

      GenrePosters.updateGenrePoster(genreID: genreID, urlExtension: "movies", completionHandler: {posters in

        for poster in posters!{

          print(poster)// prints GenrePosters(poster: Optional("/e1mjopzAS2KNsvpbpahQ1a6SkSn.jpg")) instead of just "/e1mjopzAS2KNsvpbpahQ1a6SkSn.jpg"


          self.networkManager.downloadImage(imageExtension: "\(poster)",

            { (imageData) //imageData = Image data downloaded from web
              in
              let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
              DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { //Must update UI on main thread so have to get main queue
                self.mainImageView.image = image
              })
          })
        }

      })
    }
```

Is there a way to have it so it just uses the ".jpg" instead of the entire object value?

Comment: You aren't retrieving a specific value, you're just printing the whole object.  Use `poster.poster` if you want to access the value in the `poster` property.

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Comment: @dan, enter your comment as an answer, so SwiftyJD can accept it!